# Stop a bash script when awm command returns with failure

Tags: bash, shell, awk, command-line, exit

I have the following command

```
ads2 cls create
```

This command might return two outputs, a reasonable one that looks like:

```
kernel with pid 7148 (port 9011) killed
kernel with pid 9360 (port 9011) killed
probing service daemon @ http://fdt-c-vm-0093.fdtech.intern:9010
starting kernel FDT-C-VM-0093 @ http://fdt-c-yy-0093.ssbt.intern:9011 name=FDT-C-VM-0093 max_consec_timeouts=10 clustermode=Standard hostname=FDT-C-VM-0093 framerate=20000 schedmode=Standard rtaddr=fdt-c-vm-0093.fdtech.ssbt tickrole=Local tickmaster=local max_total_timeouts=1000
kernel FDT-C-VM-0093 running
probing service daemon @ http://172.16.xx.xx:9010
starting kernel FDT-C-AGX-0004 @ http://172.16.xx.xx:9011 name=FDT-C-AGX-0004 max_consec_timeouts=10 clustermode=Standard hostname=FDT-C-AGX-0004 framerate=20000 schedmode=Standard rtaddr=172.16.xx.xx tickrole=Local tickmaster=local max_total_timeouts=1000
kernel Fxx-x-xxx-xxx4 running
>>> start cluster establish ...
>>> cluster established ...
        nodes {
            node {
                name = "FDT-C-VM-xxxx";
                address = "http://fxx-x-xx-0093.xxx.intern:xxxx/";
                state = "3";
            }
            node {
                name = "xxx-x-xxx-xxx";
                address = "http://1xx.16.xx.xx:9011/";
                state = "3";
            }
        }
```

and an unreasonable one that would be:

```
kernel with pid 8588 (port 9011) killed
failed to probe service daemon @ http://xxx-c-agx-0002.xxxx.intern:90xx
```

In both ways, I'm passing this output to awk in order to check the state of the nodes in case a reasonable output is returned, otherwise it should exits the whole script (`line 28`).

```
 ads2 cls create | awk -F [\"] ' BEGIN{code=1}               # Set the field delimiter to a double quote
 /^>>> cluster established .../ { 
               strt=1                                       # If the line starts with ">>> cluster established ...", set a variable strt to 1
            }
 strt!=1    { 
               next                                         # If strt is not equal to 1, skip to the next line
            }
 $1 ~ "name" { 
               cnt++;                                       # If the first field contains name, increment a cnt variable
               nam[cnt]=$2                                  # Use the cnt variable as the index of an array called nam with the second field the value
             }  
 $1 ~ "state" {   
               stat[cnt]=$2;                                # When the first field contains "state", set up another array called stat
               print "Node "nam[cnt]" has state "$2         # Print the node name as well as the state
               } 
           END { 
                 if (stat[1]=="3" && stat[2]=="3") { 
                   print "\033[32m" "Success" "\033[37m"    # At the end of processing,  the array is used to determine whether there is a success of failure.
                 } 
    28            else { 
    29              print "\033[31m" "Failed. Check Nodes in devices.dev file"  "\033[37m" 
    30             exit code
                 } 
                }'
   some other commands...
```

Note that this code block is a part of a bash script.

All I'm trying to do is just to stop the **whole script** (rest following commands) from continuing to execute when it goes inside `line 29` in which the `exit 1` code should actually do the job. However its not working. In other words. It prints actually the statement `Failed. Check Nodes in devices.dev file`. However, it continues executing the next commands while i expect the script to stop as the exit command in line 30 should have also been executed.

Comment: yeah, so you have `exit` there, could you please do mention what is not working there? OR may be its never going to that else block(not my downvote btw)?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I've ensured that it goes inside the else as the statement `Failed. Check Nodes in devices.dev file` is printed. Should the exit make the WHOLE script fail or only it goes outside awk?. I've also clarified my question

Comment: Please do add samples of input and expected output too in your question to make it clear, that will give us better understanding of question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 hope this clarifies my problem

Comment: Note that error messages belong on stderr.  Use `awk '{print "..." > "/dev/stderr"}'`, or if /dev/stderr is not available `awk '{print "..." | "sh -c \"cat >&2\""}'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell just `print "..." | "cat>&2"` is all you need if `/dev/stderr` isn't available. The reason `/dev/stderr` might be preferred is the stderr output is more likely to appear in synch with the stdout than when it's going to a pipe to cat and that can matter when viewing/collecting both at once.

Comment: `-F [\"]` should be `-F '"'` btw. You should always quote strings in shell (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) and you don't need to put `"` inside a bracket expression as a) it's already a regexp literal, and b) any single-char FS is taken literally anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your subject `Stop a bash script from inside an awk command` is what's getting you downvotes as trying to control what the shell that called awk does from inside the awk script is something you can't and shouldn't try to do as that would be a bad case of Inversion Of Control like calling a function in C to do something and that function deciding to exit the whole program instead of just returning a failure status so the calling code can decide what to do upon that failure (e.g. perform recovery actions and then call that function again).

You seem to be confusing exiting your awk script with exiting your shell script. If you want to exit your shell script when the awk script exits with a failure status then you need to write the shell code to tell the shell to do so, e.g.:

```
whatever | awk 'script' || exit 1
```

or to get fancy about it:

```
whatever | awk 'script' || { ret="$?"; printf 'awk exited with status %d\n' "$ret" >&2; exit "$ret"; }
```

For example:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

date | awk '{exit 1}' || { ret="$?"; printf 'awk exited with status %d\n' "$ret" >&2; exit 1; }

echo "we should not get here"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
awk exited with status 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems to be promissing. Now i get it. However, your suggestion also doesn't work, but the reason i believe is because of the output of the awk. I've edit my question. Would be happy, if you take a look at it again .)

Comment: The script in my answer is totally unrelated to any output your script produces. If the awk script exits with a failure then the shell will exit with a failure, end of story. If you reduce the code in your question to a [mcve] that can reproduce whatever problem you're having then we can take a look.

Comment: The question is, How can i find out if the the awk exits with failure?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to capture and print the awk exit status. By the way, I notice in your awk script you use `exit code` but I don't see you set the variable `code` anywhere.

Comment: @Zang322 You know that awk exits with a failure by examining its exit status.  Or are you asking how the caller of the script may know that the reason the script failed is because of an awk failure?  You do that by having your `awk` script emit a proper error message.

Comment: its mentioned at the begining "BEGIN"

Comment: OK. If you could please reduce your script to a [mcve] that'd be extremely useful to us in helping you debug it as it'd be far easier to read and see things like that. You should be able to demonstrate your problem with 1 or 2 lines of code instead of 30 or however many that is. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: I'm totally confused. One tells me to express more of  the problem/script and now you're telling me to reduce it. Please do not understand me wrongly, the question was first alot shorter and i had to explain more for clarification after being asked to do so

Comment: Maybe your original code was just brief but incomplete and so wasn't a [mcve] either? It's extremely simple - if you have a problem then create a script that's as brief (but still clear) as possible which when executed just demonstrates that problem. Don't post the whole, or even a lot, of your real/original script as that'll have a lot of extraneous detail that obscures the problem, and don't post just a segment of your real script as we almost certainly won't be able to execute that to see the problem and there's almost certainly a more concise way to demonstrate just the problem.

Comment: In addition to this excellent advice, an alternative method is to set the shell's "errexit" setting: `set -e; whatever | awk 'script'`

Comment: Here's an example of a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem: `echo "Hello" | awk '{print; exit 1}'; echo "World"` and you want to know how to stop "World" from being printed. I'm sure you can see how vastly easier it'd be for us to understand and help you with that than the code currently posted in your question.

Comment: FWIW I don't see anyone asking you to express more of the script in any of the comments and if you posted a [mcve] then you wouldn't need to express more of the problem as it'd be crystal clear from the example.

Comment: I would try it the other way. let's say i define a variable  var=0 and when the awk goes inside the else. then var=1 as well. Then i check outside the awk if the value is 1. would that work?

Comment: You didn't say if the variable `var` was an awk variable or a shell variable but if I understand you correctly then no as it sounds like you'd be trying to access the value of an awk variable in a shell script (or vide-versa). That'd be like trying to access a variable you used in a C program from whatever environment you called the C program from. The correct approach is the one I showed - awk (or any other command you call from shell) exits with a status and the shell has access to that status in the shell variable `$?`.

Comment: BTY: I tried your example showing the exit status on different commands. e.g, date | awk 'script' || { ret="$?"; printf 'awk exited with status %d\n' "$ret" >&2; exit "$ret"; }. However, it returns nothing. And to be honest, your solution (despite being so promising) still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Zang322 then your awk script is NOT exiting with a failure status. Try `date | awk '{exit 1}' || { ret="$?"; printf 'awk exited with status %d\n' "$ret" >&2; }` and you WILL see the output `awk exited with status 1` to stderr. I just updated my answer to show it working in a shell script.
`